# yaml.load() returns a map with key as bytes and not text in python 3

Tags: python, python-3.x, pyyaml

I am trying to upgrade a python 2 project to python 3. I am reading a file and loading it as a dictionary in memory. In python3 I noticed that the keys are of type bytes where as in python 2 it was text.

```
with open(LOCAL_CACHE_FILE) as local_cache:
    metrics_data = yaml.load(local_cache)
return metrics_data
```

The map looks like following in python 3

```
{b'max_write_delay': 44, b'score': 99.9980299448383, b'updated_at': 1598915750, b'write_delay': 44, b'min_write_delay': 4}
```

Input file looks like

```
CLUSTER.A:
  max_write_delay: 71
  min_write_delay: 50
  score: 100.0
  updated_at: 1596174141
  write_delay: 71
CLUSTER.B:
  max_write_delay: 71
  min_write_delay: 50
  score: 100.0
  updated_at: 1596174141
  write_delay: 71
```

The file was written in the following way.

```
with open(tmp_file_name, 'w') as tmp_file:
   yaml.dump(metrics_data, tmp_file)
```

Comment: I can't reproduce. What's in your input file?

Comment: @KlausD. Added more information .

Answer (score 0):

Found a solution for this problem.

https://github.com/yaml/pyyaml/issues/123